# Fastest way to fetch maximum x value from tuples of minimum y value?

Tags: python

I have a list `listPts` of tuples of x and y vals, for example:

> [(100.0, 400.0), (200.0, 600.0), (300.0, 600.0), (400.0, 400.0)]

Using `listPts.index(min(listPts, key=operator.itemgetter(1))` I fetch 400 as the minimum y values. As you can see, two tuples have 400 as their y value, `(100.0, 400.0)` and `(400.0, 400.0)`.

What is the fastest, cleanest way to fetch the tuple that has the maximum x value, in this case `(400.0, 400.0)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a key to compare both values, e.g.:

```
>>> min(listPts, key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[0]))
(400.0, 400.0)
```

If you want the index you can also use `enumerate()` and avoid the call to `index()` e.g.:

```
>>> index, result = min(enumerate(listPts), key=lambda x: (x[1][1], -x[1][0]))
>>> index
3
>>> result
(400.0, 400.0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm sure it's correct, but I'm getting a syntax error for the final bracket on `min(listPts, key=lambda x=(x[1], -x[0]))`. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Sorry, typo fixed. Lambda's are defined with `:` not `=`.